# Regularily loosing SSH connection rights on Hetzner Cloud

Tags: ssh

I have a strange issue regarding my setup login into my hetzner cloud via SSH.

### initial situation

I have made a fresh SSH Key, added that to a fresh Hetzner Cloud solution and made the initial login into the cloud. I was able to access the cloud via terminal with the command `ssh root@MY_IP`

### the issue

When I retry to access my server with `ssh root@MY_IP` a few days after I've made the setup, I get the following error message: `root@MY_IP: Permission denied (publickey).`

I haven't made any changes in the meantime, didn't to anything with the ssh connection, didn't created new ssh key, nothing. I don't understand why it just denies my connection try since it was working fine before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your ssh-agent was configured in a different shell?

Try listing your stored keys with

```
ssh-add -l
```

If you don't see the one you created for this specific machine/cluster, try adding it again with:

```
ssh-add <absolute_path_to_your_private_key>
```

If your agent is not even running, start it in the background with:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```